# Export database or tables from SQL Server to SQLite file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working for the web service which create the SQLite file from the SQL Server Database. And this SQLite file download by the iPhone device.

I have used the code which is download from the below URL.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB

So this code used the `System.Data.SQLLite.dll`.

In this code we get all table and create it first. After creating this table we are inserting all rows for the table. Which is very time consuming for me.

So I need to solution other way in which I can export the SQL server data into the SQLite database.

Is it any command in which we can export whole the database.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing all of the `INSERT` statements in a transaction? That should speed things up.

Comment: Hello Paul,
Nope i am using the for loop for the whole data. Can you explain me more in detail.

Comment: before loop call `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, after loop call `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. This will cut down the overall time for all of the `INSERT` statements to complete.

Comment: ok thanks paul,
let me try with transaction.